# drop and re add an index on innodb table causes slow performance

Tags: performance, query-performance, index, innodb, mysql-5.7

We just made a code and db update, that involves a table on production.
This INNODB table was "altered" by adding a new index and dropped the old one.
The new is made by 3 params and the old was 2 params.
This slow down all the performace dramatically.

The table is an "innodb" on mysql 5.7.33.

is the slowness maybe caused that the new index?
is safe to re insert the old index, and it can be a solution?
Any tips wellcome

thanks

Comment: Did you analyze the table after the new index was added?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille analyze the table put in a lock right? if yes its a problem right now

Comment: And creating the new index didn't need a lock?

Comment: Percona says that since 5.7.20, analyze no longer locks: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/03/27/analyze-table-is-no-longer-a-blocking-operation/.  Can you try it on a development database?

Comment: i did and the result is "table ok"

Comment: And on production?

Comment: Please show the indexes (before and after) and the query.  (There are several possible explanations and cures.)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I'm pretty sure any index altering will implicitly do `ANALYZE`.

Comment: `ANALYZEing` an InnoDB is so fast that any "lock" is unlikely to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

A guess...

Now that `DROP INDEX` is "instant" and `ADD INDEX` is done in the background, here is a possible explanation:

```
ALTER TABLE t
    DROP INDEX a_b,
    ADD INDEX "a_b_c" (a,b,c);
```

*may* run this way:

1. Instantly `DROP` the old index -- now the table has no index starting with `(a,b)`
2. Launch a background task to do the `ADD`.
3. Return to the user -- allowing them to perform queries *for which there may be no index*
4. Eventually the new index is finished.
5. *Now* the same query will be fast.

If that guess is correct, then this would be the cure:

1. `ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX "a_b_c" (a,b,c);`
2. Wait a while.  (No easy way to tell when it will be finished -- Watching `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is a crude solution.).
3. `ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX "a_b";`

Comment: i still investigate, ill let you know if I solve somethings, thanks for your reply!